Is there a shortcut on Android Studio to convert first letter of text after _ to uppercase?
I want a shortcut on Android Studio to convert this: my_text_is_here to myTextIsHere
when i coding on android studio convert this text manual and passed very long time.
I want a shortcut to do this operation very simple and fast
Is there a shortcut?

Does this answer your question? In Intellij, how do I toggle between camel case and underscore spaced?

@derpirscher Yes, thanks. No shortcut key for this?
